# Android: Share list?

Tags: java, android, mime-types, mime

I've created a notes list (String Array) and this list should be shared.
My code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Is there a MIME type for a list? Is this possible? (setType)
For example setType("text/array") or something like that. I searched long and I didn't find anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can put an array as an extra.

Comment: @MuratK. All receiving application may not process the array element

Comment: @Thomi May I know to which application you are intend to share the note list?

Answer (score 0):

If that just a `String Array`, simply use this method

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, String[] value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putStringArray(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

This is already defined for `Intent` class.

Sender class:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String[] strArr = new String[]{"abc","def"};
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strArr);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Receiver class:

```
String[] results = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [What's App multiline text share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039651/whats-app-multiline-text-share-intent).

```
val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("aaa", "bbb") // Some multilined text here.
val joinedText = list.joinToString("\n")

val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, joinedText)
    type = "text/plain"
}

val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```