# What's App multiline text share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-sharing

I tried to share a multi-line text using the following code, but only the last line appears.

 `val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Found this cool deal! Check it out.")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TITLE)
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MRP : $PRICE")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Deal Price : $DEAL_PRICE")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `putExtra(key, value)`, any value previous put under the same `key` gets wiped out. Try putting a single string that contains all the text you want:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
    "Found this cool deal! Check it out.\n" +
    TITLE + "\n" +
    "MRP : $PRICE\n" +
    "DEAL PRICE : $DEAL_PRICE");
```

As for the HTML content, you'll need to show us the code you used. However, you probably don't want to use `fromHtml()`; that converts HTML to styled text, which I suspect is not what WhatsApp expects to receive. Try just sending the raw HTML with the correct MIME type.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I decided I will ask the HTML part in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that only the last line appears is that a single intent can only have one value for a key.  So each time you call putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT,foo), you're overwriting the previous one.  If you want to send multiple lines, send it as a single string with '\n' characters.

As for sending html-  you'd need to tell it that you're sending html.  You're telling it you're sending plain text.  Change the mime type to text/html if you're sending html.  (Note:  I have no idea if whatsapp supports html or not, but that's the way you'd send html to any app that does support it).

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use tripple quote martks for multilined text, I'm not sure if you can in Java.

```
val moreStuff = "Text or Numbers or arrays"
 var myText = """
              line 1 of the text

              line 2 of the text
              $moreStuff
              """
```

It will format it the way you type it

```
var myText = """
    Found this cool deal! Check it out.
    $TITLE
     MRP : $PRICE
     DEAL PRICE : $DEAL_PRICE)"""
```